# Set the type of Generic (<T>) from the property

Tags: c#, .net, generics, properties

I want to achieve as per below

```
// Property
public static T Type
{ get; set; }

private void Form1_Load(...)
{
    List<Type> abc = new ...
    // code.....
```

As mentioned above, when I load `Form1`, a `List` must be defined of the type = `Type (the property)`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: use a generic method to create your List

Comment: What is `T`? A generic parameter of the class that contains the code?

Comment: Assume two classes. From the `MainForm`, I select `Class1`, then in `Form1`, the type of the `abc` must be `Class1`. i.e. `List<Class1> abc = new ...`

Comment: You can't use the **content** of a property to set/derive the type of your list. You could use the **Type** of a property, so the proerty with generic type must be within a generic class.

Comment: So how to achieve this without Properties.

Answer (score 2):

`Type` is the name of the property, `T` is the type name.

```
List<T> abc = new List<T>();
```

I'm assuming of course that you've parameterized the enclosing class as `class CustomForm<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to set that using a property, or if that is at all possible - Do you want to be able to change the type after instantiation or something?

If you don't have some very special needs, perhaps you could just use this?:

```
private void Form1_Load<T>(...)  // Pass the type in here
{
    List<T> abc = new List<T>(); 
}
```

Usage:

```
this.Form1_Load<targetType>(...);
```

Alternatively, pass the type in when you instantiate the class containing Form1_Load():

```
class Container<T>
{
    private void Form1_Load(...)
    {
        List<T> abc = new List<T>(); 
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var instance = new Container<targetType>();
```

Comment: I am making reports using objects as data source. http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/13169999-ef3b-496c-b502-caef973c3bb2/Using%20ReportViewer%20in%20WinForms%20C  Now what I want to do is, load all the reports in one form that is `Form1` in my example. As you can see in Form1_Load event in the link, `Student` class is set as type of `List<>`. Now assume that there is another report for teachers' details and I want to load it in the same form. I will make another class for `Teachers Details` and load it to the `Form1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class builder like this:

```
public class GenericBuilder
{
    public Type ParamType { get; set; }

    public object CreateList() {
        var listType = typeof(List<>);

        ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();
        alist.Add( this.ParamType );

        var targetType = listType.MakeGenericType( (Type[])alist.ToArray(typeof(Type)) );

        return Activator.CreateInstance( targetType );
    }
}
```

and then you could use it:

```
var builder = new GenericBuilder();

builder.ParamType = typeof( int );

var result = builder.CreateList();
```